# Parsing this format of data into a new one?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I have a format which returns me some dates and I need to parse it into something else which I find a little bit complicated.

The data format is `Mon Dec 24 2018 9:00:00` as a `startDate` for example and `Friday Dec 28 2018 17:00:00` as an `endTime` for example. What happens here is that I select I want someone to start on Monday at 9 until 17 everyday, but what my data does is makes it look like he's working non-stop.

I have tried mapping over it and putting it onto objects with days of the week and start and end times, but I ran into a problem because I create the object like

```
dates : {
    monday: {
        start: 9:00,
        end: 18:00
    },
    tuesday: {
        start:9:00,
        end:18:00
    }
// etc for everyday of the week
}
```

But, what if I only need Monday through Thursday, for example, that would be a problem. Anyone has any idea, how could I do that, in any other way? I was thinking about using `moment.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I think you want to list all days between two different dates, here is an example of function that iterates over days by using [moment.isSameOrBefore](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/) and [moment.add](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) functions, hope this help:

```js
  function toDays(startDateString, endDateString) {

    const startDate = moment(startDateString, 'dddd MMM DD YYYY');
    const endDate = moment(endDateString, 'dddd MMM DD YYYY');

    const dates = {};

    while(startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate, 'day')) {
       const currentDay = startDate.format('dddd');
       dates[currentDay] = {start:'9:00', end:'18:00'};
       startDate.add(1, 'days');
    }

    return dates;

  }


  const result = toDays('Monday Dec 24 2018', 'Friday Dec 28 2018');

  console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm, what if my string comes with everything at once, weekday month  day year and hour

Comment: @CristianDuma, then you should change the format according to the datetime string, something like this: `const startDate = moment(startDateString, 'dddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss');` if you want to include hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: I would like to, but I'd have to get rid of the dates in this case, right? I have tried some stuff but i broke it because i don't really understand moment